# Where are FSharp.Core release notes?

Tags: f#, nuget, documentation, release-notes

Where can I find release notes for FSharp.Core packages (https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Core/) ? I visited project's site on GH, but apart from a discussion on where these should be put I haven't found much more.

I'm mostly interested in differences between 4.7.2 and 4.7.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the GitHub repository release notes:

https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/releases

https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/master/release-notes.md

They both seem pretty unmaintained.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen these. Nothing for 4.7.2 FSharp.Core though.